# How to make an attribute inside an entity read-only?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, orm

I have this attribute (that is a collection) inside an entity. It is formed by doing a JoinTable with another table. Is it possible to make whatever updates are performed on this attribute by other services/clients/views/etc. to not be saved into the database?

So in other words, I just want to extract from the database this attribute, but I don't want to save its updated state back in. The reason is I have another way of updating these columns in the database and that should be the official way to update this column, then later I can read the updated values with this attribute again.

Edit: Here is some code

```
Class Person:

@JoinTable(name="PERSON_DEPENDENCY",  
             joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "parent_id")  
             inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "child_id"))  
Set<Person> children;
```

There is another similar annotation for property parents (just parent_id and child_id is swapped from above annotation). If A is the parent of B, saving A's children will result in a row where parent_id = A's id child_id = B...while saving B's parents will also result in the same exact row. Ideally I want to just save 1 of these collections and that should be sufficient, but at the same load both to quickly know the parent/children of a person.

Comment: Could  you show us some code fragment, e.g. your entity definition?

Answer (score 3):

Set the "insertable" and "updatable" attributes of the @Column annotation for that field to be "false".

Comment: Its actually a Map...key Long and value another Entity....not sure if that qualifies as a "basic type". I'm using a JoinTable annotation already to get this mapping.

Comment: Sorry, the insertable/updatable are actually on the Column annotation not Basic, so pick the appropriate column that you don't want updating

Comment: As someone else's request I added some annotation code, will your solution still work? I suppose for one of the collections I need to add insertable/updatable inside both the joinColumns?

Answer (score 0):

A solution is to use field based annotation, to declare your fields as protected and to propose only public getter. Doing so, your objects can not be altered.

(This solution is not entity specific, it is just a way to build immutable objects)

Comment: That still doesn't fix it, remember I have another way of updating the columns this gets mapped to. So even if this field is not touched, I don't want hibernate to persist the data on this field because it will be inaccurate when hibernate times to persist the data. I really need a way for hibernate to load properly this field from the database, but completely ignore it (to avoid inconsistencies) when it comes to persist it

Answer (score -1):

Transient Fields
Transient entity fields are fields that do not participate in persistence and their values are never stored in the database (similar to transient fields in Java that do not participate in serialization). Static and final entity fields are always considered to be transient. Other fields can be declared explicitly as transient using either the Java transient modifier (which also affects serialization) or the JPA @Transient annotation (which only affects persistence):

```
@Entity
public class EntityWithTransientFields {
    static int transient1; // not persistent because of static
    final int transient2 = 0;  // not persistent because of final
    transient int transient3; // not persistent because of transient
    @Transient int transient4; // not persistent because of @Transient
}
```

The above entity class contains only transient (non persistent) entity fields with no real content to be stored in the database.

Answer (score -2):

Mark the Field as `@Transient`. Transient Fields are not saved or read from the database.

Comment: Are they still load from the database? So I can just add this annotation on top of whatever other mappings I am doing, and it will still load the data properly from the database but just not be saved back in?

Comment: Transient means NOT persisted (or read). It does not mean READ ONLY

Comment: Yes I need the field read from the database so @Transient wont work